# Not able to ping between two routers

Tags: networking, routing, ping, modem

I have a network setup in my house as shown in the picture. The green arrow show that I am able to ping and the red arrow show that I am not able to ping. The IP addresses and subnet are given. I have tried using the LAN and WAN port on the Router 2. Still doesn't work

Also, LAPTOP 4 IS NOT ABLE TO PING LAPTOP 1 AND 2

[image: Here is a photo of my network]

Comment: Router 2 should have two IP addresses, one external and one internal address. Your diagram only shows the external address (or have you configured the internal to 192.168.1.2?). The external address is generated by router1.

Comment: Your diagram is not complete. What are the different subnets you're routing between, what are the IP addresses of the routers in those subnets, and are you absolutely sure you need to have two routers in your network (as opposed to just a single subnet with switches)? The cause is probably that Router 2 does not know how to reach the subnet with laptops 1 and 2 and router 1 does not know how to reach the subnet with laptops 3 and 4. You have to tell the routers how to reach them.

Comment: @Robert The internal IP is 192.168.1.2 and the external IP is 192.168.2.1